# predicate on relationship Vs predicate on attribute which is best?

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, nspredicate

There might be already answer somewhere but i am not find it so sorry for asking such stupid question

There is two entity parent and child

[image: image with relationships]

I want all child of parent then i will get using relation ship like below predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent = %@", parent]
```

---

[image: image with attributes]

> i am storing parent_id in child table as an attribute

and use predicate like

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent_id = %@", parentid]
```

**now my question is which give batter performance and how?**
as i am confusing why i have use relationship model as i can find it with attribute

Answer (score 2):

Both versions make this much more complicated than it needs to be. If you have an instance of `Parent` in a variable named `parent`, you can get every related `child` by looking up the value of the relationship directly, without performing a fetch or using a predicate of any kind.

```
NSSet *children = [parent valueForKey:@"child"];
```

Or if you created a subclass of `NSManagedObject` to represent instances of `Parent`,

```
NSSet *children = parent.child;
```

[Incidentally it's probably a good idea to rename the `child` reference to something like `children`, since it's a to-many relationship.]

Of your examples, the first is... less inappropriate, I'll say. It's still more complex than it needs to be, but Core Data provides relationships the exact purpose of **relating entities**. Storing foreign keys as in your second example is mis-applying SQL-style thinking to a non-SQL API.

Comment: I am using NSFetchedResultsController i don't know how to use NSSet/NSArray to show data in UITableview can you give me some advice for that?

Comment: It should be easy for an `NSArray`, because it supports things like asking how many objects are in the array and looking up the object at an index. An `NSSet` can be sorted into an array by using `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`

Comment: but it's also create issue. if `NSSet` is update then i have to again fetchallobject from `NSSet` to create `NSArray` so this also making app slow

Comment: Hello sir can you reply for this questions comments as they conflict with your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/q/39076283/4734164

Comment: Which part of that question contradicts this answer, exactly? You did not seem to be aware of how to use Core Data relationships, and I explained that. Your comments on this answer describe a **completely different question** than the one you asked here, and that other question of yours is **that question**, not the one you asked here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure on how CoreData works internally, but I would strongly assume that relationships are better. I guess by using them you're basically following pointers, whereas using a predicate results in a search over your instances of a certain entity.

Obviously CoreData does some things like a relational database (using sqlite as default storage and so on), but since the tutorials tell you to use relationships for what you wanna do I'm pretty sure it relies on that somehow for optimization. the predicates are more suited for specific searches or "work-arounds" for some cases that would require a defined connection "parallel" to the data model.